# How to manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'?

Tags: dpkg

I was trying to remove Adobe flash player and then install again but terminated the process. Later when I tried to repeat, it doesn't allow me to `sudo apt-get remove flashplugin-installer`.

I get this message:

```
dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal window and enter

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Note the results, and post here if problems recur and you can't afterwards run

```
sudo apt-get remove flashplugin-installer
```